# How to repeat a function for all rows for each col in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, repeat

I have a df with 150 rows values, and I would like R to loop or otherwise repeat the following for each row and column in the df;

Example of data

```
df <- data.frame('criteria1' = c('x','1', 'X', '', 'X'), "criteria2" = c('y','3', '', 'X', ''), "criteria3" = c('y','7', '', 'X', 'X'))
```

If a X appears in a row, I would like the function to take the values from the two first rows, and paste them together with a '=' between them. The following works fine for the first column.

```
df$criteria1 <- ifelse(df$criteria1 == 'X', paste(df$criteria1 [1], '=', df$criteria1 [2]),'')
head(df)
```

The problem is when I try to do it for all the columns in the dataframe

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(df$x== 'X', paste(x[1], '=', x[2]),''))
```

All cells become NA. I have tried with different versions of the code above, but nothing gives the expected output which is;

```
head(data.frame('criteria1' = c('x','1', 'x=1', '', 'x=1'), "criteria2" = c('y','3', '', 'y=3', ''), "criteria3" = c('y','7', '', 'y=7', 'y=7')))
```

Comment: What is `K` here? Did you mean `df`?

Comment: Yes, K was the name of my original dataframe, I forgot to change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` instead of `lapply`... there are many references for the difference between the two, but I believe the issue comes from the fact that ifelse applies to a vector, and not a list, and so you cannot pass it to lapply.

```
sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == 'X', paste(x[[1]], '=', x[[2]]),''))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway that I can keep the content in all the rest of the cells which does not contain X (inclusive the two first rows)? something like  df <- sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == 'X', paste(x[[1]], '=', x[[2]]),[original content])) . I have tried df <- sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == 'X', paste(x[[1]], '=', x[[2]]),x)) but that just make all the other cells weird :)

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution:

**EDIT**

Based on @Chuk P's comment(see below),the following is an edit to the answer:

```
 df %>% 
   mutate_all(~ifelse(.=="X",paste0(.[[1]],"=",.[[2]]),""))
  criteria1 criteria2 criteria3
1                              
2                              
3       x=1                    
4                 y=3       y=7
5       x=1                 y=7
```

This is comparable to the output below:

```
ifelse(df$criteria1 == 'X', paste(df$criteria1 [1], '=', df$criteria1 [2]),'')
[1] ""      ""      "x = 1" ""      "x = 1"
```

**Original answer(see comments,answer left here in case it may be useful in the future)**

```
df %>% 
   mutate_all(~ifelse(.%in%c(letters,LETTERS),paste0(.,"=",.[grep("\\d",.)]),.))
```

Or using `dplyr` >= 0.8.89.9000:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),~ifelse(.%in%c(letters,LETTERS),
                                     paste0(.,"=",.[grep("\\d",.)]),.)))
```

Result:

```
   criteria1 criteria2 criteria3
    1       x=1       y=3       y=7
    2         1         3         7
    3       X=1                    
    4                 X=3       X=7
    5       X=1                 X=7
```

If you want blanks instead:

```
 df %>% 
   mutate_all(~ifelse(.%in%c(letters),paste0(.,"=",.[grep("\\d",.)]),.[!.%in%LETTERS]))
  criteria1 criteria2 criteria3
1       x=1       y=3       y=7
2         1         3         7
3                              
4         x                   y
5         1         y         7
```

**NOTE**:

Simpler methods to do this may exist. This is to add variety to the answers.

Comment: looking at his desired output @NelsonGon  above (last block starts with `head` I think we can simplify your answer even more to `df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ifelse(. == "X", 
                     paste0(.[[1]], '=', .[[2]]), 
             .)
)
`

Comment: @ChuckP Thanks, I tried to avoid using [[1]] and [[2]] since they seem hardcoded and may not generalise(not sure though)

Comment: Generally agree but it seems to be explicitly what he's looking for leaving those two rows as is.  Also note your results don't always show `y = 3` and `y = 7` which seems to be a requirement...  Run his head and you'll see it.

Comment: I have tried to run this solution df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),~ifelse(.%in%c(letters,LETTERS),
                                     paste0(.,"=",.[grep("\\d",.)]),.))) but gets the msg:  could not find function "across" . I have tried to update both dplyr) and plyr

Comment: Use `mutate_all`. The version with `across` has not been released on CRAN yet. Do `mutate_all(~ifelse(and other code))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mapply` here, i.e.

```
df[] <- mapply(function(x, y)replace(x, x == 'X', y), df, paste(df[1,], df[2,], sep = '='))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   criteria1 criteria2 criteria3
> 1         x         y         y
> 2         1         3         7
> 3       x=1                    
> 4                 y=3       y=7
> 5       x=1                 y=7
> ```

Comment: why not just use sapply with one variable as OP had it? the fundamental issue comes from passing ifelse to lapply.

Comment: @doubled Why not show another way of doing it? And maybe introduce something much better to use than `ifelse`??

Comment: good point! I guess personally I struggled a lot with understanding when you can pass certain functions to apply functions, and that seemed to be key here (and i hadn't had my coffee yet, sorry :( ).

Comment: It seems OP wants blanks instead?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. It does not matter whether the two first rows are blank, actually, I prefere it this way, to check the the results afterwards. However, when I run this; df[] <- mapply(function(x, y)replace(x, x == 'X', y), df, paste(df[1,], df[2,], sep = '=')) I get NA's?